# next() function in jquery is not working as expected

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I know this is a duplicate question, but that question doesn't help me, because my problem is a little different.

This is my `html` code :

```
<select class="selector">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div class="show" style="display:none;"></div>
```

This is my `jQuery` code :

```
if($('.selector').val()=="volvo")
   $(this).next('.show').show();
```

So, what I want is, if the `<selector>` has the value "volvo", its next div(which has the class "show") will show up, otherwise not. Here, I am not using any `change` event. I want this happen after the page has been loaded.

I tried this too :

```
if($('.selector').val()=="volvo")
   $(this).next().show();
```

But same result, nothing happens, the `<div>` doesn't show up.

What should I do now ?

Comment: Create a fiddle first

Comment: Please spend a bit more time in the [jQuery Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/). You seem to lack the basics, sorry.

Comment: A one-liner to top it off: `$('.selector:has(option[value="volvo"]:selected)').next().show()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class selector is used as `.class` with a `.` preceding the class name.

```
$('.selector').val()
```

Without a event handler `$(this)` cannot refer to the `select` element, it refers the `window` element.

Use the following code,

```
var $selector = $('.selector');
if($selector.val()=="volvo")
   $selector.next('.show').show();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vw3FS/)**

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `this` not referring to the element with class `selector`. It will refer to `window` only. Change the code like,

```
var selector=$('.selector');
if(selector.val()=="volvo")
  selector.next().show();
```

Comment: Should not run the selector twice. Save the result in a variable instead. Also, in which browser would `this` refer to `document`? (after making these changes your answer would become the same as Shaunak's, so you could as well delete it)

Comment: Open your browser's console, type `this` and press Enter :). Of course if the code runs in a `$(document).ready()` handler, `this` will refer to `document`. Depends on the situation.

Answer (score -1):

Dude. There is no need to be so complicated

**HTML**

```
<select class="selector">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div class="show" style="display:none;"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($('.selector').val()=="volvo")){
      $('.show').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: I am just using the elements he created. It its advisable to use ID.

Comment: Yeah, you're just making a very specific answer to a question that is most probably broader so that the OP will most probably come back with another problem induced by your answer. Note that as your answer will work in this specific case so I wasn't the one downvoting it

Answer (score -1):

Without the event context `$(this)` has no meaning. Also, this statement is wrong :

```
if($('selector').val()=="volvo")
```

and should be written :

```
if($('.selector').val()=="volvo")
```

or

```
if($('select.selector').val()=="volvo")
```

in which case you can then write :

```
if($('select.selector').val()=="volvo")
    $('.selector').next('.show').show();
```